# How to set a flag from an input value

Tags: github, github-actions

I am building a GitHub Actions workflow, and my application has some optional flags.

Is there any way to create a condition in the arguments if an input exists?

Something like:

```
args:
    - if ${{ inputs.myfield }}' --myfield
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
args: 
    - ${{ inputs.myfield && '--myfield' }}
```

In case *myfield* has any value, this will result in:

- *entrypoint* "--myfield"

otherwise:

- *entrypoint* ""